# How can I exclude a source named test.js from being detected to be test file in a create react app?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, react-scripts

In a create-react-app application, I have named a source file :

`/src/config/env/test.js`

Unfortunately, jest is now trying to execute it as a test,

I have tried to add the following in my `package.json`:

```
"jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "!<rootDir>/src/config/env/test.js",
      "!<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ]
}
```

But I still have this error:

```
FAIL src/config/env/test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestScheduler.js:256:22
```

I am using **react-scripts**  2.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution here would be using the [`testPathIgnorePatterns` configuration value](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-array-string), like this:

```
"testPathIgnorePatterns": ["\/test.js"]
```